# customise Telr payment web view in iOS

Tags: ios

I am integrating Telr Payment in my App. After sending request to Telr (https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/mobile.xml) it is returning start url for web view and everything is working fine but is there any way to customise that web view.

Comment: is there any way to customise that web view ....? not clear

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mobile>
  <webview>   <start>https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/webview_start.html?code=c1caa42eb2a65875cceda816e710</start>
    <close>https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/webview_close.html</close>
    <abort>https://secure.innovatepayments.com/gateway/webview_abort.html</abort>
    <code>c1caa42eb2a65875cceda816e710</code>
  </webview>
  <trace>4000/5863/5875cced</trace>
</mobile>
this is the response I'm getting

Comment: how can we change layout of this view in <start>

Comment: sorry no idea..

Comment: Hi, I think Telr Payment Gateway's Hosted Payment Page V2 provides a facility to customise the Web Page. You can provide your customised CSS files and images and upload them on your Telr Account under Integration -> Payment Page V2.

I never tried but this is what their document said.

Comment: Hi thanks it worked finally the issue was with css file our designer created

Comment: Hi, i am integrating telr, i am facing issue and getting error response, can I see your xml which u r sending ?